# I have a very big js react project I want to search some specific words in the project but there are 2400 words

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, search

I have a very big js react project I want to search some specific words in the project but there are 2400 words so I cant use ctrl shift search of vsc I need a plugin or a program which takes 2400 words as an input then search the entire project and tell x word used 5 times in this project. I tried this program it does not work

```py
import os

def search_text_in_directory(directory, text_to_search):
    total_occurrences = 0
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".js"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    content = f.read()
                    occurrences = content.count(text_to_search)
                    total_occurrences += occurrences
                    if occurrences > 0:
                        print(f"'{text_to_search}' found in '{file_path}'")
    
    return total_occurrences

directory_to_search = r"C:\Users\hmmer\newsapi-app"  # Your project directory path
text_to_search = "news-image"
total_occurrences = search_text_in_directory(directory_to_search, text_to_search)
print(f"Total occurrences of '{text_to_search}': {total_occurrences}")
```

Comment: you haven't actually explained why you can't use the search across files feature of VS Code. you just said it doesn't work. From what I know of that feature, what you are claiming makes no sense to me.

Comment: your script only searches for 1 word not 2400

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, Updated after you comment made your issue clearer. This will loop through your words, and print out the desired information.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEXT_ARRAY=( "cat" "dog" )

for TEXT_TO_SEARCH in "${TEXT_ARRAY[@]}"
do
  RESULT="$(grep -oR "${TEXT_TO_SEARCH}" --include \*.js | wc -l | xargs)"
  echo "Total occurrences of '$TEXT_TO_SEARCH': $RESULT"
done
```

---

```
grep: Searches for patterns etc.
 -o: Prints only the matching part of the lines.
 -R: Recursively search subdirectories listed.  (i.e., force grep to behave as rgrep).
 [-i]: Perform case insensitive matching.  By default, grep is case sensitive.
 --include: If specified, only files matching the given filename pattern are searched. ...

wc: Counts words etc.
 -l: The number of lines in each input file is written to the standard output.

xargs: Using to trim the response.
```

Comment: Great advice but for text_to_search part I have 2400 words which has to be listed and say like x word used 10 time y word used 0 times etc..